# Update Existent Matplotlib Subplot with a user input

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I am currently trying to implement a 'zoom' functionality into my code. By this I mean I would like to have two subplots side by side, one of which contains the initial data and the other which contains a 'zoomed in' plot which is decided by user input.

Currently, I can create two subplots side by side, but after calling for the user input, instead of updating the second subplot, my script is creating an entirely new figure below and not updating the second subplot. It is important that the graph containing `data` is plotted first so the user can choose the value for the input accordingly.

```
def plot_func(data):

    plot_this = data

    plt.close('all')

    fig = plt.figure()

    #Subplot 1
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    ax1.plot(plot_this)
    plt.show()

    zoom = input("Where would you like to zoom to: ")
    zoom_in = plot_this[0:int(zoom)]

    #Subplot 2
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    ax2.plot(zoom_in)

    plt.show()
```

The code above is a simplified version of what I am hoping to do. Display a subplot, and let the user enter an input based on that subplot. Then either edit a subplot that is already created or create a new one that is next to the first. Again it is crucial that the 'zoomed in' subplot is alongside the first opposed to below.

Comment: Are you aware that the usual matplotlib plotting window already has a [Zoom tool](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html) implemented?

Comment: I did not! Thanks for the link. Although I am not so much trying to actually zoom as much as I am trying to plot a portion of a larger data set parallel to itself. Perhaps zoom is the incorrect word.

Comment: So maybe you are looking for [something like this](http://gtk3-matplotlib-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zooming.html)?

Comment: Yes similar to that, although not as complicated. I do not need to display the second plot within the first, just have them side by side.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not very convenient for the user to type in numbers for zooming. The more standard way would be mouse interaction as already provided by the various [matplotlib tools](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html).

There is no standard tool for zooming in a different plot, but we can easily provide this functionality using <kbd>[`matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector`](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector)</kbd> as shown in the code below.

We need to plot the same data in two subplots and connect the RectangleSelector to one of the subplots (ax). Every time a selection is made, the data coordinates of the selection in the first subplot are simply used as axis-limits on the second subplot, effectiveliy proving zoom-in (or magnification) functionality.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import  RectangleSelector


def onselect(eclick, erelease):
  #http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html
  xlim = np.sort(np.array([erelease.xdata,eclick.xdata ]))
  ylim = np.sort(np.array([erelease.ydata,eclick.ydata ]))
  ax2.set_xlim(xlim)
  ax2.set_ylim(ylim)

def toggle_selector(event):
    # press escape to return to non-zoomed plot
    if event.key in ['escape'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
        ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())


x = np.arange(100)/(100.)*7.*np.pi
y = np.sin(x)**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

#plot identical data in both axes
ax.plot(x,y, lw=2)
ax.plot([5,14,21],[.3,.6,.1], marker="s", color="red", ls="none")
ax2.plot(x,y, lw=2)
ax2.plot([5,14,21],[.3,.6,.1], marker="s", color="red", ls="none")

ax.set_title("Select region with your mouse.\nPress escape to deactivate zoom")
ax2.set_title("Zoomed Plot")

toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box',  interactive=True)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing tool, thank you for this! I tested it out and it works flawlessly. I do have one issue though and that is that I am running my script in a Jupyter Notebook which is why I was interested in the user input method. Is it possible to allow this functionality in a  notebook?

Comment: @neerbasu The fact that you want to use jupyter notebook is an important piece of information that should have been added in the question. I have absolutely never used jupyter, but isn't the whole story about notebooks that the user can enter any value anyway, directly into the code? Why would you need `input` then? I also have the suspicion that my interactive example from above will not work in jupyter.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry I did not mention that before seeing that it is a crucial factor. My apologies. The good news is that I did find a bit of code that allows the same functionality as you mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

```
%matplotlib inline
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

Comment: You need to provide some minimum information in how far those 3 lines are an answer to your question. Someone how comes to this site will not at all understand what those lines mean and where to put them.